# Fluidtypo3: Use custom field as title of FCE

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

I don't want to use the default header in my FCE's, but only custom flux fields. In the backend list views my FCE's are shown as "[no title]" because the default header is not filled. This leads to much confusion for editors.

How can I define one of my custom flux fields to be used as title for the FCE in TYPO3 Backend list views etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use a field from the flexform, because all fields from the FCE are stored in the same field in the database (`pi_flexform`).

What you can do is to render the content element title with a user function. It is registered with a line like this in the TCA config:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['label_userFunc'] = 'Vendor\\Extkey\\Utility\\ContentElementLabelRenderer->getContentElementTitle';
```

The user function itself could look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extkey\Utility;

/**
 * This class renders a human readable title for FCEs,
 * so one is able to find a content element by its headline.
 */
class ContentElementLabelRenderer implements \TYPO3\CMS\Core\SingletonInterface {

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\FlexFormService
     * @inject
     */
    protected $flexFormService = null;

    /**
     * Returns the content element title for a given content element
     */
    public function getContentElementTitle(&$params) {

        if (null === $this->flexFormService) {
            $this->flexFormService = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Service\\FlexFormService');
        }

        if (ctype_digit($params['row']['uid']) && 'fluidcontent_content' === $params['row']['CType']) {

            // If this is a FCE, parse the flexform and template name and generate the 
            // title in a template specific way.
            $row = $params['row'];
            $additionalRowData = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetSingleRow('pi_flexform, tx_fed_fcefile', 'tt_content', 'uid = ' . $row['uid']);
            $flexFormContent = $this->flexFormService->convertFlexFormContentToArray($additionalRowData['pi_flexform']);

            $lastColonPosition = strrpos($additionalRowData['tx_fed_fcefile'], ':');
            $contentElementType = (FALSE === $lastColonPosition) ? 'invalidtype' : substr($additionalRowData['tx_fed_fcefile'], $lastColonPosition + 1);
            switch ($contentElementType) {

                case 'Image.html':
                    $params['title'] = 'Image: "' . ($flexFormContent['title'] ?: $flexFormContent['subtitle']) . '"';
                    break;
                default:
                    $params['title'] = 'Unknown content element type';
                    break;
             }
        }
        else {
            // If this is not a FCEm, print out "normal"    
            // title. Not the real thing, but comes pretty close, hopefully.
            $params['title'] = $params['row']['header'] ?: ($params['row']['subheader'] ?: $params['row']['bodytext']);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces a maintainance problem though: Every time you add or change a content element, you have to update this file.

Comment: I finally got to test your solution and it works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: This worked for me with TYPO3 6.2, but didn't with TYPO3 7.6. In my case the class `ContentElementLabelRenderer` was not found, though namespaced correctly. I had to add `require_once \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath( 'myext' ) . 'Classes/Utility/ContentElementLabelRenderer.php';` to make it work.